# How do I check if an object is "empty" or not?

Tags: java

The Cube class have two constructors, one which accepts three parameters that are converted into the tree attributes of the cube, and another one that doesn't require any parameter and therefore creates an "empty" cube. My question is how can a boolean method check if the cubes are valid or empty? Is there a way to do that without the need of checking each one of the attributes?

```
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cube c1 = new Cube(4, 3, 6);
        Cube c2 = new Cube();

        System.out.println(isNotEmpty(c1));
        System.out.println(isNotEmpty(c2));
    }

    public static boolean isNotEmpty(Cube cube) {
        if (/*cube attributes are NOT empty*/) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class Cube {
        private int height;
        private int width;
        private int depth;

        public Cube() {}

        public Cube(int height, int width, int depth) {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.depth = depth;
        }

        public int getHeight() { return height; }
        public int getWidth() { return width; }
        public int getDepth() { return depth; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `width == 0 && height == 0 && depth == 0`?

Comment: Why isn't isEmpty a method of the Cube class?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by [empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937316/how-do-i-check-if-a-object-is-empty)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a object is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937316/how-do-i-check-if-a-object-is-empty)

Comment: @shmosel They must have the same teacher

Comment: @ScaryWombat Who knows, they might be the same student...

Comment: Hehehe GBatt is a classmate of mine indeed. By empty I mean without a specific value on its attributes.

Comment: @BernardoAraujo Then you should ask yourself: how did you represent "without a specific value on its attribute".  An `int` always contains a value.  Even for reference, `null` is a value.  We usually use special values to represent an "uninitialized" value.  For example, it is meaningless to have height being negative, then you can set it to `-1` to represent "no value".  Another way is to use some flags (e.g. a boolean that by default is false, and set to true if you are assigning values.  Another way is to use something like `Optional<Cube>` instead of simply `Cube`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that the only state which a `Cube` has are the height, width, and depth, then you could actually just use `null` to represent an empty `Cube`.

It doesn't make much sense to call a cube with no dimensions a cube in the first place.  Using `null` as a marker might make the most sense.

Comment: should maybe get rid of the useless constructor

Answer (score 0):

Use a bool flag `isEmptyCube`  in the constructor. At the time of object creation, it will be automatically marked correctly whether it is blank or not.

```
public static class Cube {
        //...
        private boolean isEmptyCube;
        public Cube() {isEmptyCube = true;}
        public Cube(int hight, int width, int depth) {
            //...
            isEmptyCube = false;
        }
        public isCubeEmpty() { return isEmptyCube;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change one (or more) of your int fields to be an Integer Object, or introduce a new Boolean field `isSet` or get rid of your empty constructor

1) If you use an Integer Object you can test to see if it is `null` where -as `int` primitives have a default value of 0

2) If you have a Boolean field you can default it to `false` and set it to `true` in your proper constructor

Answer (score 0):

It seems a so tricky question. At first, we have to have any criteria: `What is an empty object?`. When we have some criteria, even single, we must check it.

From the reason when we are considering the `Cube c3 = new Cube(0, 0, 0)` like is not empty, so, here is one of ways:

```
public class CubeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cube c1 = new Cube(4, 3, 6);
        Cube c2 = new Cube();
        Cube c3 = new Cube(0, 0, 0);

        System.out.println(c1.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(c2.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(c3.isEmpty());
    }

    static class Cube {

        private int hight;
        private int width;
        private int depth;
        private boolean isEmpty;

        public Cube() {
            this.isEmpty = false;
        }

        public Cube(int hight, int width, int depth) {
            this.hight = hight;
            this.width = width;
            this.depth = depth;
            this.isEmpty = true;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return this.isEmpty;
        }

        public int getHight() {
            return this.hight;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return this.width;
        }

        public int getDepth() {
            return this.depth;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: what about `Cube c3 = new Cube(0,0,0);` ?

Comment: It works well for me. I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: OP asks - *Is there a way to do that without the need of checking each one of the attributes?*

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you think about it?

Comment: Sure, but nothing that other answers have not addressed